# Display loading message until complete SQL data retrieve

Tags: c#, winforms, long-running-processes

I'm using WeifenLuo dockpanel-suit.

I need to show  some kind of splash form or loading message before SQL complets loading data.

What I've tried didn't work

```
  public partial class frmPostventa : DockContent
    {
       private void frmPostventa_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   

            bool done = false;
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((x) =>
            {
                using (var splashForm = new SplashForm())
                {
                    splashForm.Show();
                while (!done)
                    Application.DoEvents();
                splashForm.Close();
            }
        });
        //Database task heavy load
        cargarDatos();
        done = true;

    }

    public void cargarDatos()
    {

        string strSQL = "exec SAI_ALGO.spPostventa";

        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, strCon);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        // Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource.
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

    }


}
```

EDIT: Added CargarDatos()

Comment: Note that usage of DockPanel Suite is not relevant to this problem, this is simply a "long running process on the UI thread" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoEvents()` nearly always leads to a very bad place, and should pretty much always be avoided.  The problem with this particular implementation is that your long running process (`cargarDatos()`) is going to block the UI thread until it completes, so `DoEvents()` will have no effect; it will not interrupt a method while it is executing (assuming `cargarDatos()` isn't doing something internally that would yield the thread). Also, creating and interacting with a UI control from some background thread is not valid here.

You should use a `BackgroundWorker` to perform the long running operation and raise status updates to the UI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx

Comment: " Also, creating and interacting with a UI control from some background thread is not valid here." I just add 'CargarDatos()'. Will it work with this approach? I'm reading about 'BackgroundWorker' Thank you @roken